# Export redshift table data to csv file tabs using lambda python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have a table metric_data that has data in the below format:

[image]

I want to export this data into csv file in S3 with separate tabs for components. So I will have 1 file with 3 tabs - COMP-01, COMP-02, COMP-03.

UNLOAD function is able to export all the data from the table to one CSV file. but how can I export the data as separate tabs in the CSAV file? Below is the UNLOAD command I am using:

```
unload ('select * from mydb.metric_data')   
to 's3://mybucket/demo/folder/file.xlsx' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

This command generates one csv file with all the data from the table. How can I export the data as separate sheets in a single CSV file?

**UPDATE**: as CSV doesn't support multiple sheets, I am trying to implement the same with excel. So i updated the Unload command to generate excel file and it produces one file with all the table data

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The CSV file format doesn't support tabs / sheets.  You will need to convert the CSV file to a different format (like .xls for example) that does support multiple sheets in one file.

Also the UNLOAD command you posted will produce multiple files, not just one. You can add the PARALLEL OFF option to make one file but this will only work for output files less than 5GB.

Comment: Gotcha. I still want to implement the same in xls/xlsx. I ran the above command it produces only 1 file. I want to break this data to 1 excel with multiple sheets

Comment: Hmm.  By default Redshift produces 1 file per slice up to 5GB is size.  What is the distribution style / key of the table?  Also check that the file is being written by UNLOAD as Redshift will append slice and part number to your S3 key.  So you should see something like s3://mybucket/demo/folder/file.xlsx000_part_000.  If you want the files to have a suffix like .csv you need to use the EXTENSION option.  I also see that you changed your UNLOAD to point to a .xlsx file but this won't change the format of the unloaded files.  You will need Lambda and python to convert .csv to .xlsx

Comment: Yeah, I have modified my approach. I am importing redshift table to Pandas dataframes and again exporting them as 1 excel file with multiple sheets

Comment: For now, that seems to be efficient way because I need to generate csv, then convert to excel and then break them into multiple sheets